# Find extra work done by Bob

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, algorithms

Alice has challenegd Bob game of N puzzle.N puzzle is played on N*N grid with each cell containing distinct numbered tile from 1 to N*N-1 Except one which is empty cell and represented as 0.

**Move Type 1 :** Bob can pull out any tile he want and put it into any cell of his choice (not necessarily blank)

**Move Type 2 :** He can choose any tile and move it to any adjacent cell in 4 direcions regardless of weather cell is empty or not.

**Goal to be achieved :** Goal is to reach configuration where first row contains tiles 0,1,2..N-1 second row contains N,N + 1,N + 2..2*N-1 and last row contains N*(N-1)...N*N-1

**Now we need to help Bob in finding how much extra work he will have to do if he chooses Move Type 2** which means if given position can be solved optimally using Move Type 1 in X moves and using Move Type 2 in Y moves then we need to find (Y-X) extra work.

Example : Let M=N*N=4 and initial configuration be

```
0 2 
3 1
```

Here answer will be 1

Explanation : Using Type 1 move Bob can put out tiles 1,2,3 and put them in reuired order this takes him X=3 moves

Using Type 2 move he can move tile 1 UP,tile 2 DOWN and then LEFT and then tile 3 RIGHT to reach final goal.So Y=4

Hence Y-X=4-3=1

Comment: Move-type #$2$ sounds like a subset of move-type #$1$ (in other words, it is redundant). Can you please clarify this?

Comment: @barakmanos subset in what sense ?

Comment: @BarryCipra Yeah right.

Comment: @BarryCipra  Yeah i done that..thanx for pointing it out

Comment: @BarryCipra Ohh sorry ..it was typing mistake.Actually it was N*N and not N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Each tile moves independently.  For Type 1 moves, Bob has to move each tile that doesn't start out in the right place once.  At a maximum he will make $N^2-1$ moves.  For Type 2 moves, each tile has to move the [Manhattan distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manhattan_distance) that it starts from its final spot number of times.  Each tile moves from $0$ to $2N-2$ times.  To get the average, note we can consider the two axes independent.  In one axis and the continuous approximation, the [average distance](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/SquareLinePicking.html) is the average distance between points in a unit square $\frac 1{15}(2+\sqrt 2 +5 \sinh^{-1}1 \approx 0.521405433$ times the size of the square $N-1$ so on average Bob will move $2(N-1)(\frac 1{15}(2+\sqrt 2 +5 \sinh^{-1}1)$ moves.

Comment: Actually its not what is actually required.I need to find extra moves not an average moves and why the initial configuration doesnt matter here

Comment: The initial configuration does matter.  If you start with everything where it belongs, Bob does no work either way, so no extra work in Type 2.  There isn't a simple answer.  For Type 1 moves, there is a clear maximum, which I gave. Most arrangements will be close to that as the average number of tiles that start out in the correct location is $1$.  There is also a maximum for Type 2, but it isn't as easy to calculate.  For a given initial condition it is easy to calculate the number of moves and I sketched the algorithm.